# Missing Math Symbols in LibreOffice/OpenOffice

Tags: 11.04, fonts, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I've had this problem for about six months, but I haven't been able to find a solution.

When viewing documents with writer or presentation containing math symbols/fonts, some of the symbols are either replaced with question marks or just left blank. The integral symbol is an example.

I can post some documents or system output for example if that would be helpful. I recently upgraded to Natty x64 (with packaged LibreOffice), but I've had this issue with Maverick x64 & OpenOffice as well.

I've downloaded msttcorefonts and cleared my font cache. For what it's worth, I also did a clean install for Natty.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the file format of the document? If they are online then it would help to link to it.

Comment: Could you give an example, esp. showing the textual command? There are [examples for integrals](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Math_commands_-_Reference#Operators), do they work for you?

Comment: Its hard to analyze without a sample document. Do not hesitate to file a bug with the file attached!

Comment: This is a bug report and [as such is off-topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/). :)